# Filter month in mysql when date is in varchar

Tags: mysql

I have a 2 columns called **id** and **publish_date**. **publish_date** is in varchar format(e.g. 2015-11-08 20:11:59). I used the following code to filter results based on month:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(publish_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = 11
```

MySQL returned an empty result set. What's going on?

Comment: The expression on the left side of the comparison is returning NULL. And NULL  doesn't ever "equal eleven".  And that expression is returning NULL because that's the result of the conversion of the string value to DATETIME, because the format specified (as the second argument to STR_TO_DATE) doesn't match the format of the strnig value. MySQL can't convert the string to a DATETIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had referred to the function manual, you'd see the second argument is supposed to be the given date format.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

If you're varchar entry is `2015-11-08 20:11:59` then you need to specify a format of `'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'`

Comment: Ooops. I meant to write '%y/%m%d' format. But yeah, I should have used the '-' instead of '/'. This is what happens when you're working on an empty stomach:( Anyways, thank you all who have answered.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `TIMESTAMP()`.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MONTH(TIMESTAMP(publish_date)) = 11
```

## Demo:

```
mysql> select MONTH(TIMESTAMP('2015-11-08 20:11:59'));
+-----------------------------------------+
| MONTH(TIMESTAMP('2015-11-08 20:11:59')) |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                      11 |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query, when you convert date from varchar to date you can give that format which is used in column like ('%Y-%m-%d' for 2015-11-08)

I assume your publish_date (2015-11-08) format is `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(publish_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 11;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your character timestamp is of the format

```
2015-11-08 20:11:59
```

Therefore your format string which you pass into `STR_TO_DATE()` should be

```
%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s

SELECT *
FROM 'table'
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(publish_date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')) = 11
```

For documentation on how to use various types of format strings, I prefer [TechOnTheNet](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php).

Answer (score 0):

The format specified in STR_TO_DATE doesn't match the format of `publish_date`.

(Is there any good reason why `publish_date` isn't defined as a DATETIME column?)

Test your conversion, using a different format, one that matches the format of your strings...

```
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(publish_date,'%Y-%m-%d %T')
    FROM `table`
   LIMIT 10
```

That second argument to STR_TO_DATE function has specific meaning. It's not just a jumble of gibberish.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Given the format of publish_date string matches the default format for MySQL DATETIME, you could omit the explicit reference to STR_TO_DATE function:

```
 MONTH(publish_date) = 11
```

But personally, I would include the STR_TO_DATE function, to make the conversion explicit.

But if I had to do what you need to do, comparing VARCHAR values, I wouldn;t bother with converting it to date, I'd just use SUBSTRING function to extract the 5th thru 8th characters

```
 SUBSTR(publish_date,5,4) = '-11-'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as per below-

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(publish_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 11;
```

Here you have to understand that you are trying to convert your string to date format means here you need to tell mysql that in which format your string is not in which format you want to convert-

To understand it if your date string is suppose '08/11/2015 20:11:59' then your query should be-

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(publish_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) = 11;
```

Hope now it will be clear to you.